# How to communicate to Windows Service through WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I have Windows Service, which is running tasks on timer tick. I also selected to communicate with Windows Service through WCF named pipe channel. I can create WCF Service instance and open it for listening. But how I access objects relying in Windows Service via WCF?

This is what my Windows Service looks like:

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private ServiceHost m_svcHost = null;  
    private myObject = null;

    ...

    // Run this method from external WCF client
    private void SomeMethod()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (m_svcHost != null) m_svcHost.Close();

        m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyCommunicationService));
        m_svcHost.Open();

        // initialize and work with myObject
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (m_svcHost != null)
        {
            m_svcHost.Close();
            m_svcHost = null;
        }
    }
}
```

So what I want, to have access to myObject within WCF Service, when client will make inquiry. Or even run a method on myObject.

Comment: This question needs much more clarification. Add information showing your progress this far. Also what objects are you trying to access?

Comment: Updated. Basically I need to control Windows Service activities, query its state via WCF Service.

Comment: You just need a command channel between the `MyCommunicationService` instance and your Windows Service instance. You can achieve that in many ways, via a static property for instance.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I have to open 2 communication channels in my case, one to external client and one local for Windows Service? Then this `MyCommunicationService` will act solely as proxy, right? Is it common pattern for WCF?

Comment: @Pablo No, I did not mean that you need extra communication channel between your WCF service and it's host. You can implement this communication without any abstraction via a simple static property.

Comment: @Zverev Eugene: then your answer with sample would be much appreciated...

Comment: @Pablo Here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a communication channel between your `MyService` (WCF Hosting entity) and the `MyCommunicationService` (WCF Service instance) simply using a static property:

```
//This can be put into a separate DLL if needed.
public interface IMyHostCallbacks
{
    void HostCallback(string iSomeDataFromWCFToHost);
}

public static class Host
{
    public static IMyHostCallbacks Current;
}
```

---

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase, IMyHostCallbacks
{
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //Set the static callback reference.
        Host.Current = this;

        if (m_svcHost != null) m_svcHost.Close();

        m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyCommunicationService));
        m_svcHost.Open();

        // initialize and work with myObject
    }

    //Here you have data from WCF and myObject available.
    void IMyHostCallbacks.HostCallback(string iSomeDataFromWCFToHost)
    {
        //Be careful here. 
        //Depending on your WCF service and WCF clients this might 
        //get called simultaneously from different threads.
        lock(myObject)
        {
            myObject.DoSomething(iSomeDataFromWCFToHost);
        }
    }
}
```

Surely you can even put the static field into your `MyService` class but at least some abstraction between `MyService` and `MyCommunicationService` would not hurt.

---

Now, in any place in your `MyCommunicationService` you can:

```
void WCFServiceMethod()
{
    Host.Current.HostCallback("some data");
}
```

Comment: I see. Basically it's a singleton pattern with controller object. If there will be no other ways, I will accept this answer pretty soon.

Comment: @Pablo Yes but do not mess things up with the singleton term. It is the windows service instance that is single here. WCF service can have many instances. As long as windows service is singleton by default and that is the only way to have it, you do not call it singleton. I do not quite get what you mean with the controller object here.